# Qt QFormLayout align label to left and value to the right

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have the following QFormLayout with a short-value row and a long-value row

```
layout = QFormLayout()
layout.setLabelAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
layout.setFormAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)

layout.addRow(QLabel('Label short'), QLabel('2'))
layout.addRow(QLabel('Label long'), QLabel('1234567890'))
```

What I get is:

```
Label short    2
Label long     1234567890
```

What I would like is:

```
Label short             2
Label long     1234567890
```

I will call the first column the label column and the second column the value column.

- Using `setFormAlignment()`, I can move the entire form to the left or to the right, but the value column alignment stays the same
- Using `setLabelAlignment()`, I can change the label column, but not the value column
- Using `setAlignment()` does not seem to have any effect

Is there an endpoint for controlling the alignment on the second column?

Comment: change to `QLabel('2', alignment=Qt.AlignRight)`, You must apply the alignment to the QLabel, not the QFormLayout

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        layout = QFormLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.setLabelAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        layout.setFormAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)

        layout.addRow(QLabel('Label short'), QLabel('2',          alignment=Qt.AlignRight))
        layout.addRow(QLabel('Label long'),  QLabel('1234567890', alignment=Qt.AlignRight))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Alright, so there must be something wrong with my code, since I have exactly that (but with other widgets around) and it does not work. The labels in fact shrink to text (I verified by adding `QLabel{background: red}` to the stylesheet. I will decompose my app, see if I can trace the issue. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using a QLabel you should be able to set the horizontal text alignment to the right using AlignRight

Something like (using C++, but you have the same options in Python)

`label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom | Qt::AlignRight);`

Comment: I tried, it does not work. Not even when I do `label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)`